# Any solutions for unsupported fonts to be able to print via POSBOX for odoo POS?

Tags: odoo, python-unicode, point-of-sale

Any solutions for unsupported fonts to be able to print via POSBOX for odoo POS? POS BOX does not support Myanmar font. We need to print via POS BOX because we need multiple printings (to kitchen 1, to kitchen 2, to drink counter, etc ...). Any solutions for this issue, please?

Comment: Can you able to change font type? Or just add your custom fonts in POSBOX via proxy and other way is create a css file and add this in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one maybe it could help you to solve the problem:

Just try to make changes in default addons of your odoo. Because there are some configuration is there related to font printing. There is one module name hw_escpos in that module you can find one function where font configuration is there so just add font what you want and try to print.